# How to declare a vector of pointers to objects of a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, vector

The thing is that I am struggling with making objects of the class **Shape**. I declare the vector, but then do not know how to connect it to the class **Shape** and its objects. The code itself has one base class, which is **Shape** and then two subclasses **Circle** and **Rectancle**. The idea of the code is to use a vector in the main function, and have multiple cases for the **Circle** area and the **Rectangle** area. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual double GetArea() const = 0
    {

    }

private:

};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(double p, double r) // constructor
    {
        pi = p;
        radius = r;
    }

    Circle() : pi(3.14), radius(0) {} // default constructor

    void SetRadius(double value)
    {
        radius = value;
    }

    double GetRadius() const
    {
        return radius;
    }

    double GetArea()
    {
        double area = pi * radius * radius;
        return area;
    }

private:
    double pi = 3.14;
    double radius;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(double a, double b) // constructor
    {
        sideA = a;
        sideB = b;
    }

    Rectangle() : sideA(0), sideB(0) {} // default constructor

    void SetSideA(double value)
    {
        sideA = value;
    }

    double getSideA() const
    {
        return sideA;
    }

    void SetSideB(double val)
    {
        sideB = val;
    }

    double getSideB() const
    {
        return sideB;
    }

    double getArea()
    {
        double Area = sideA * sideB;
        return Area;
    }

private:
    double sideA;
    double sideB;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Shape*> shape;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you're confused at how to go about populating the vector? If you only had one `Shape *` and you wanted to stick a `Circle` in it, do you know how you'd go about it?

Comment: Your code will not compile like it is. Please change ```virtual double GetArea() const = 0
    {}``` to ```virtual double GetArea() const = 0;```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want *Polymorphism*. You just use the constructor of the circle or the rectangle, for example:

```
vector<Shape*> shape(1);
if(/* case is circle*/)
  shape[0] = new Circle();
else
  shape[0] = new Rectangle();
```

---

However, you need remove the definition of the pure virtual method in the base class, since it's [inside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation), and only declare it.

Then, you need to implement that method, by using *exactly* the same prototype, so you need to mark the method in Circle as `const` too. Same for Rectangle class, where you also did a typo, since the name of the method is "GetArea", not "getArea".

---

Complete Minimal Working Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual double GetArea() const = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {};
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(double p, double r) // constructor
    {
        pi = p;
        radius = r;
    }

    Circle() : pi(3.14), radius(0) {} // default constructor

    void SetRadius(double value)
    {
        radius = value;
    }

    double GetRadius() const
    {
        return radius;
    }

    double GetArea() const
    {
        double area = pi * radius * radius;
        return area;
    }

private:
    double pi = 3.14;
    double radius;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle(double a, double b) // constructor
    {
        sideA = a;
        sideB = b;
    }

    Rectangle() : sideA(0), sideB(0) {} // default constructor

    void SetSideA(double value)
    {
        sideA = value;
    }

    double getSideA() const
    {
        return sideA;
    }

    void SetSideB(double val)
    {
        sideB = val;
    }

    double getSideB() const
    {
        return sideB;
    }

    double GetArea() const
    {
        double Area = sideA * sideB;
        return Area;
    }

private:
    double sideA;
    double sideB;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Shape*> shape(2);
    shape[0] = new Circle(3.14, 1);
    shape[1] = new Rectangle(2, 3);

    for(auto s : shape)
      std::cout << "Shape area = " << s->GetArea() << endl;

    // When you are done, delete the dynamically allocated memory.
    // You can use smart pointers in order to avoid doing this manually (and maybe forget!)
    delete shape[0];
    delete shape[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Shape area = 3.14
Shape area = 6

where the first area is from the circle, and the second area from the rectangle.

I suggest you read: [Virtual destructor in polymorphic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363817/virtual-destructor-in-polymorphic-classes) and [What is the 'override' keyword in C++ used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198314/what-is-the-override-keyword-in-c-used-for)

---

After doing all this for practice, you should really start using [smart pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/), like this for instance `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shape;`, instead of raw pointers. This way, you won't have to worry about deleting manually dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204003/discussion-on-answer-by-gsamaras-how-to-declare-a-vector-of-pointers-to-objects).

Answer (score 3):

For starters the class Shape must have a virtual destructor

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual double GetArea() const = 0
    {

    }

    virtual ~Shape() = default;
};
```

Within the class the member function `GetArea` is declared with the qualifier const. So in derived classes the overriding function shall also have the qualifier const.

```
double GetArea() const override
{
    double area = pi * radius * radius;
    return area;
}
```

and

```
double getArea() const override
{
    double Area = sideA * sideB;
    return Area;
}
```

In main you can use the member function push_back to append pointers to objects, For example

```
std::vector<Shape*> shape;

Shape *p = new Circle( 3.14, 10.0 );

shape.push_back( p );

p = new Rectangle( 10.0, 20.0 );

shape.push_back( p );
```

Instead of the vector of the type

```
std::vector<Shape *> shape;
```

you could use a vector of `std::unique_ptr<Shape>`. For example

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SHape>> shape;
```

In this case you will not need to delete the pointers manually for example by using the standard algorithm `std::for_each` for the vector.

Comment: I was ready to use unique pointers as well, but you got 1st there, nice! :) Please though, check up the pure virtual method in the base class. :) Just like in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59272561/2411320).

Comment: @walnut Thanks. It was a typo.