# C++ virtual functions inheritence

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>
class a{
  public:
    a(){};
    virtual ~a(){
      std::cout << "del class a";
    }
};

class b: public a{
  public:
    ~b(){
      std::cout << "del class b";
    } 
};

int main(){

    a *pa;
    pa = new b;
    delete pa;

}
```

Hi, I'm fairly new to C++. Looking at the code example above, `class b` does not have a virtual destructor, but when the program executes, the output is
`del class b` then `del class a`.

I'm wondering why that's the case, as I have not created a virtual destructor in `class b`. Does that mean by declaring the base destructor virtual, the "virtualness" of the derived class is implicit?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual destructor in polymorphic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363817/virtual-destructor-in-polymorphic-classes)

Comment: Yes, "virtualness", not only in case of destructor, is implicitly derived.

Comment: @NutCracker No, i was talking more on the lines of why calling a non virtual and derived destructor makes sense. But thanks for resource anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Even though destructors are not inherited, if a base class declares its destructor virtual, the derived destructor always overrides it. This makes it possible to delete dynamically allocated objects of polymorphic type through pointers to base.

You can find more in [Cppreference-Virtual destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)